# MySQL database entry duplication

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP script search script that logs every query made in a MySQL database starting with 1 in the value column. Currently, if the same terms are searched more than once, 1 is added to the number in the value column. However, after two searches for the same word, the query gets added to the database again. Why could this be?

My PHP code is:

```
<?php

$database=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database",$database);

$query=$_GET['q'];

logQuery($query);
function logQuery($query){
$query="insert into queries (query) values ('$query') on duplicate key update value=value+1";
mysql_query($query);
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you post your table schema?

Comment: What is the PRIMARY_KEY you base the `duplicate key` query on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like either `query` is not your primary key, or that $query is different from the DB contents. My money is on the key; could it be a composite key? i.e. `id` AND `query`?

In this situation/example, using `mysql_escape_string(trim($query))` is a MUST to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Do you define query field as unique? maybe a whitespace or something, try using md5 as unique key

Answer (score 0):

If the query is getting added a second time, then it is obviously not a primary key, which prevents the 'on duplicate key' from working